# Install packages in texworks missing style files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, miktex, texworks

So I am trying to install the `pgfplots` package in LaTeX on my Windows 7 machine.
I usually did this by just running the LaTeX file with `\usepackage{pgfplots}`,
  and then the computer asks me if I want to install the packages.
I click yes, but I look in my style files under the `pgf` folder and do not find the appropriate style file.
My error message is

```
======================================================================
pdflatex.EXE: Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
pdflatex.EXE: Data: Invalid syntax

======================================================================


! LaTeX Error: File `pgfplots.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Comment: Can you give the output of `mpm --version`?

Comment: MiKTeX Package Manager 2.9.4220 (MiKTeX 2.
Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Christian Schenk

Comment: It seems that one solution is to reinstall MiKTeX and specify to 'install packages on the fly without asking', but there should be a way to simply change the setting.  Can you start the package manager manually? (Should be under Programs > MiKTeX 2.9 > Package Manager.)

Comment: I would poke around in the menu system of MiKTeX's package manager for the setting.  What I think is happening is that `pdflatex` is interactively asking permission to install a package whereas TeXworks is expecting it to be a batch run (that is, not interactive).  I unfortunately don't have access to a Windows box, so I can't walk though it myself.

Comment: @SeanAllred TeXworks is fine with MiKTeX's 'install on the fly' method: it's only TeXniccenter that has a problem with that in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update your MiKTeX system.  Your package manager version is `MiKTeX Package Manager 2.9.4220` (I guess MiKTeX 2.8), but the current one is `MiKTeX Package Manager 2.9.4620 (MiKTeX 2.9)`.

For me it seems that your package manager is not syncronisized with the database in internet. So it tries to load a package that is not longer available or the name has changed or ...

If you install the complete MiKTeX version, you will not have problems with the "install on the fly". Update your packages with the package manager once a month.

Comment: re-installing MikTeX did not work. I checked what package manager this gave me and it was 2.9.4497 (which is still a lower one that you mentioned)

Comment: so I opened up package manager and tried to sinc with the repository and got "Windows API error 5: Access is denied."

Comment: this is what I did using the website http://miktex.org/ and downloading the newest version (is that button not the "complete" one)

Comment: oh I think I just fixed it. The front page download does not recognize whether you have a 64bit or 32bit machine and hence I was using the wrong version. Not quite sure how this would screw things up but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem, but it turned out I had typed *pfgplots* instead of *pgfplots*. Can be awfully hard to spot in the error message

> LaTeX Error: File `pfgplots.sty' not found.

... just writing this in case it happens to someone else.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it is because I installed the 32 bit version, while my Windows is a 64 bit system. After reinstalling the correct version of MiKTeX, everything works fine.

Comment: Downvoters should leave a comment explaining how the post could be improved.

Comment: @Adam: This answer cannot be improved, because it is simply wrong. I run myself a 32bit MiKTeX on a 64bit Windows, and this has `pgfplots` included. I once have installed this with the Package Manager.

Comment: @Speravir that's still information that could prompt either a revision or deletion of the answer, and it's information that would be useful for the user, in my opinion.

Comment: @user1627187 This may have worked, but is not the real solution, because many others including me do not have any problem with the 32bit version on a 64bit Windows system. You should BTW know, that in 64bit MiKTeX `biber` is missing.

Comment: @Adam: See my comment to OP of answer. We were crossing.

Comment: @Adam This is a strange answer, because it seems to be just repeating my comment from 2013 saying the 64 bit worked for me, but I don't know why. It adds nothing new to the conversation and is more of a comment than an answer